# Ruby on Rails Development Process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, process

We are a small team that is about to start developing a localized version of a successful US web app in Korea, using RoR.

Our question is: What process would you recommend we use to go about developing the app?

Should we start with the data models? The views in HTML and then code them? Take a single feature, develop it and then add additional features as necessary?

Comment: This is not a good question for Stack Overflow as there is no correct answer, only very subjective ones. I would recommend reading through some Rails tutorials, either online or in some books to find the alternatives. Rails itself dictates the initial process, but once the framework is created by Rails, the rest is an iterative process and only you, and your team can determine what that will be.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

This question has no right answer. It depends on too many factors, such as:

- project size
- team size
- how experienced the developers are with rails
- how experienced the developers are with this kind of project

I would use different development method for different combination of those factors.

EDIT: You can try https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ with this question.

Comment: +1 for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to disagree with the chorus singing "no right answer", though I will agree that this question is not ideal for Stack Overflow. However, I think I do have an answer...

I think you should use an [Agile development method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) and incrementally add features in order of importance.

Someone or a small team should prioritize features.

You should always have a working application.

Add one thing at a time. Write tests. Iteratively develop your entire system with one user story at a time.